# Four-to-Many Relationship with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

I am using Laravels Eloquent ORM and i ran into a little problem with a special relationship. Lets assume i have the following table:

```
Recipe:
   id | ... | ingredient1 | ingredient2 | ingredient3 | ingredient4
```

Every recipe has exactly 4 ingredients and i get the data from an external source in this specific format, thats why i have the ingredients as columns and not as a normal many-to-many relation.

I could set these up as 4 one-to-many relations, but i want to be able to write `$ingredient->usedInRecipes()->get()`.
 With 4 one-to-many relations i would have to write `$ingredient->usedInRecipesAsIngredient1()->get()`, [...], `$ingredient->usedInRecipesAsIngredient4()->get()` and merge them after afterwards, which would result in 4 queries.

If you know a good way to join these before querying the database or how to make a 4-to-many relation work please answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work in all my use cases.

In the Recipe model i defined the 4 ingredients as One-to-Many relations and made two helper scope functions.

```
class Recipe extends Eloquent { 
    public function ingredient1()
        { return $this->belongsTo('Ingredient', 'ingredient1'); }
    public function ingredient2()
        { return $this->belongsTo('Ingredient', 'ingredient2'); }
    public function ingredient3()
        { return $this->belongsTo('Ingredient', 'ingredient3'); }
    public function ingredient4()
        { return $this->belongsTo('Ingredient', 'ingredient4'); }

    public function scopeHasIngredient( $query, Ingredient $ingredient ) {
        return $query->  where( 'ingredient1', '=', $ingredient->id )
                     ->orWhere( 'ingredient2', '=', $ingredient->id )
                     ->orWhere( 'ingredient3', '=', $ingredient->id )
                     ->orWhere( 'ingredient4', '=', $ingredient->id );
    }

    public function scopeWithIngredients( $query ) {
        return $query->with('ingredient1', 'ingredient2',
                            'ingredient3', 'ingredient4');
    }
}

class Ingredient extends Eloquent {
    public function ingredientForRecipes() {
        return Recipe::hasIngredient( $this )->withIngredients();
    }
}
```

To get all recipes for an Ingredient i can now call `$ingredient->ingredientForRecipes()->get()` and use the ingredients without extra queries.

Answer (score 1):

From the question I can't tell if you have already attempted this or not although as I see it you just need to use a single many-to-many relationship.

Each ingredient presumably has a common set of properties that can all be handled in one table `ingredients`.

```
id    name        created_at                updated_at
1     Paprika     01/01/1970 00:00:00       01/01/1970 00:00:00
1     Rosemary    01/01/1970 00:00:00       01/01/1970 00:00:00
1     Basil       01/01/1970 00:00:00       01/01/1970 00:00:00
1     Oregano     01/01/1970 00:00:00       01/01/1970 00:00:00
```

Then your `recipes` table

```
id    name        created_at                updated_at
1     Herb Soup   01/01/1970 00:00:00       01/01/1970 00:00:00
```

To hold the relationships, a pivot table `ingredient_recipe`

```
id    recipe_id   ingredient_id
1     1           1
2     1           2
3     1           3
4     1           4
```

Now all you require is a `belongsToMany` relationship on both your `Recipe` and `Ingredient` model.

You can code safeguards to make sure one recipe only ever has 4 relationships with ingredient if you wish but to keep it simple:

```
Recipe::with('ingredients')->get();
```

Would retrieve all the ingredients along with the recipe.

[You can read more about this relationship in the documentation here.](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many)

**Without Pivots**

If you kept the columns `ingredient_1`, `ingredient_2` and so on in the `recipes` table you could add something like this to your `Recipe` model.

```
public function scopeGetWithIngredients($query)
{
    $query->leftJoin('ingredients i1', 'recipes.ingredient_1', '=', 'i1.id')
          ->leftJoin('ingredients i2', 'recipes.ingredient_2', '=', 'i2.id')
          ->leftJoin('ingredients i3', 'recipes.ingredient_3', '=', 'i3.id')
          ->leftJoin('ingredients i4', 'recipes.ingredient_4', '=', 'i4.id')
          ->select('recipes.name', 'i1.name AS ing_1', 'i2.name AS ing_2');
}
```

You can then just get the ingredients in your model with

```
Recipe::getWithIngredients();
```

Comment: Yes i could do that, but i was looking for a solution without the pivot table, because some other projects access the same database. If no one has a good solution for that i will use a pivot table and adjust the other projects.

Comment: @darthmaim ok, fair enough. I'd still go down the pivot route personally as it is feels much more normalised. Saying that I've added in an untested approach you could use to get the ingredients using fluent joins and a scoped method on your model.

Comment: awesome, i will try that out.